# Sum aggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a sql database from where I load data into elasticsearch using logstash. I am trying to find the sum of a colum for which I wrote an elastic search aggregation query. But when I cross check the result with that from the sql data base `SELECT SUM(column) from table`, the result is not the same but has a difference of about 2000. The document count in elasticsearch is same as the number of records in sql database. I am trying to find a justification for the difference in results of a simple sum of a column..

Elasticearch Query:

```
{
  "_source":"false",
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*"
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "range":{
          "aggr_time":{
            "gte": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000",
            "lt":  "2016-01-20  T00:00:00.000",
            "time_zone": "+00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "Granulated Date Reports":{
      "date_histogram":{
        "field":"aggr_time",
        "interval":"year"
      },
      "aggs":{
        "Sum.needed":{
          "sum":{"field":"Column"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any chance there's a badly configured mapping for "Column" (e.g. string instead of integer/float)?

Comment: I don't think so, It is mapped to "double"

Comment: Any change that the data retrieved before the aggregations is smaller than in your sqldb?